# "Future isn't a type" on Flutter beta channel but not on stable channel?

Tags: flutter

I just switched to the beta channel with my project and it seems that `Future` is no longer recognized. E.g.,

```
import 'dart:async';

Future<int> setNumberSlowly(int number) async {
  return Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200), () => number);
}
```

The `Future<int>` is squiggle underlined with the error `Future isn't a type`. It also doesn't like `Future.delayed`.

My Flutter stable version is 3.7.0. My Flutter beta version is 3.10.0-1.1.pre.

Comment: It seems like your IDE is very confused.  Does restarting it help?  Does `flutter analyze` report the same issue?

Comment: @jamesdlin I tried your suggestion and restarted AS but the problem remained. I installed Flutter with `asdf` and am wondering if that confuses things. When I run `flutter channel beta` and `flutter channel stable` it seems to work as intended and `flutter --version` reports the change.

Comment: Again: does `flutter analyze` report the same issue?

Comment: @jamesdlin Sorry. No, `flutter analyze` does not report the error.

Comment: Hmm. I just opened the folder and ran it fine with VSCode. When I click on `Future` intellisense navigates to `Future.dart` as expected, but not with AS.